# League of Legends RADS Error

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

Just recently, within the past 2 weeks, whenever I run the League of Legends launcher, the small splash screen pops up, stays up, and then is replaced by this window:
[image]

Here are some of the fixes I've tried:

- uninstalling League
- pretty much everything in [this](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2540385) thread

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running league as admin? That solved many of my problems with getting the game to launch

Comment: Yup, my default launcher is the admin launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem a few weeks ago where nothing would work. If you've tried this, I apologize. My solution may be in that thread but I didn't see it. I had to change my DNS server to make it work. To do that:

1. Open the network and sharing center
2. On the left hand side click 'Change adapter settings'
3. Find the adapter you're currently using
4. Right click it and choose properties
5. Click 'Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)'
6. Click properties, and modify it from:

[image]

to

[image]

By doing this, you are changing from whatever your default DNS server is to Google's DNS servers. If your DNS server is acting up, your LoL client won't be able to connect while Google's servers are working for me. If it doesn't work, you may want to change it back. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! This fixed the problem perfectly for me.

Comment: didnt work for me :(